# Change Password every week for root user script

Tags: linux, unix, scripting, change-password

I got request to change root Password for every 10 days in all Linux based machines and these are production machines and Enabled with grub password so in case we forgot/missed password both root/grub password we cannot recover.

I have wrote a simple script which redirect password to file that is nfs shared file. So it writes password to nfs shared file for every week.

Below is the file format

```
 Machine1:
 Machine2:
 Machine3:
```

we will execute script like

```
 sh autopass.sh Machine1
```

so it change root Password for the Machine1 and replace Machine1 old Password with new Password in nfs share file. So we will send password to authorized users every week

Below is  script

```
#!/bin/sh 
#Function to create Random Password
function randpass() {
[ "$2" == "13" ] && CHAR="[:alnum:]" || CHAR="[:graph:]"
cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd "$CHAR" | head -c 8
echo
}
#Get Random Password to rootnewpass variable
rootnewpass=`randpass`
#Replace new password in file rootpass
sed -i "s/^\(${1}:\).*/\1${rootnewpass}/" /nfs/rootpass
#Change new Password using new random generated keyword 
echo -e "root:$rootnewpass" | chpasswd
```

So Now I wanted here is my approach is good or any other way  is better to implement this. Here concern is at any chance i should not misplace the password meaning should not redirect wrong password to file.

Same concept I am using for grub password as well.

Note: All machines should not have same root password and hence i have opted this option.

Please advice

Comment: You are violating a fundamental rule on password security writing the password to disc. I'm not sure the extra security your are trying to achieve isn't already outweighed by the risks of managing the password in a way that exposes it not only in memory, but on disc. One file gives whoever is smart enough to access it the keys to the kingdom. I'm interested in the other thoughts you will get.

Comment: Sagar, your approach is not good, but just because there's no good approach to do what you want. At some point this new password will be written to disk, and there's where the problem is. If you store the password encrypted, then at some point your script will have to provide the key to the encryption, therefore also making it not safe. I don't know of any method of changing the password via a script that is safe.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the password of the root user on a batch of servers (100 servers: 10.1.0.1 to 10.1.0.100) by:

```
# for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do \
ssh 10.1.0.$i 'echo -e "newpassword\nnewpassword" | passwd  --stdin root'; \
done;
```

Make it a cron job and this should work.